# Thank you note to sb vs. Thank you note for sb [American English]

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage, american-english

I am in the middle of interviewing for a new job. I wanted to thank the hiring manager for the interview, but I don't have their email.

I decided to write to the recruiter and asked politely to pass along my message. I was wondering if it's correct to write "Thank you note for Susan Miller" using the preposition "for" instead of "to" as an email subject line.

Subject #1: "Thank you note **for** Susan Miller"

Subject #2: "Thank you note **to** Susan Miller"

Which one is correct in American English and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you explain in the body of the email what you're asking for, both of those are correct and natural, though they have slightly different meanings.

*A note **for** Susan Miller* means a note intended for delivery to Susan Miller. We assume the note is addressed to Susan, but that's not explicit. So if this is your email's subject line, the subject is *your request to pass the note on*.

*A note **to** Susan Miller* means "a note addressed to Susan Miller". There's no suggestion that is should be passed on to her. So if this is your subject line, the subject is *the note itself*.

IMO, it makes a bit more sense for the subject to be your request to the recruiter, rather than the note itself, so I'd go with "for".

---

Tangent: This is none of my business, but it would probably look better if the email came directly from you, so if you could get Susan's email address from the recruiter and send the note yourself, that would probably be better than (a) relying on the recruiter to forward it, and (b) cutting off any response Susan might want to send you in return.